# Dynamic SQL for multiple (common table) databases solution?

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, view, dynamic-sql

I've been using a dynamic SQL query (in a stored procedure) in order to run a single statement for a number of similarly structured databases with common tables.

For example:

**Solution 1:**

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[Example]
    @vc_db VARCHAR(16)
    , @vc_example VARCHAR(32)

AS
BEGIN

-- Dummy query for SSRS to allow columns to be read in Visual Studio

IF 1 = 2
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        T1.C1
        , T1.C2
        , T2.C3
        , T2.C4
    FROM 
        DB1.dbo.T1
    LEFT JOIN
        DB1.dbo.T2
    ON
        T2.C1 = T1.C1
    WHERE
        T2.C4 = @vc_example
END

-- Dynamic query

DECLARE @vc_SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = '
    SELECT 
        T1.C1
        , T1.C2
        , T2.C3
        , T2.C4
    FROM 
        ' + @vc_db + '.dbo.T1
    LEFT JOIN
        ' + @vc_db + '.dbo.T2
    ON
        T2.C1 = T1.C1
    WHERE
        T2.C4 = ''' + @vc_example + '''
'

PRINT @vc_SQL
EXEC (@vc_SQL)

END
```

This has been working great so far since it allows us to pass additional parameters through whilst running the statement/report for multiple databases.

However, as queries have grown far more complex, it is becoming a difficult task to both manage the dummy query, as well as converting the standard SQL into the dynamic format.

Therefore, we've started looking into other ways to achieve this.

**Solution 2**

Our latest solution has been to create a view for each common table (with the addition of a database column), essentially in the format:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[v_T1]
AS

SELECT *, 'DB1' DB FROM DB1.T1

UNION ALL

SELECT *, 'DB2' DB FROM DB2.T1

UNION ALL

SELECT *, 'DB3' DB FROM DB3.T1
```

This has allowed us to write queries (within a stored procedure) in a much simpler and easier fashion (no conversion into a "dynamic query" and no need for a dummy query to be picked up by Visual Studio), instead utilising the additional database column to limit and join the data, such as below:

```
SELECT 
    T1.C1
    , T1.C2
    , T2.C3
    , T2.C4
FROM 
    v_T1
LEFT JOIN
    v_T2
ON
    v_T2.C1 = v_T1.C1
    AND v_T2.DB = v_T1.DB   -- JOIN condition on database to limit data
WHERE
    v_T2.C4 = @vc_example
    AND v_T1.DB = @vc_db    -- WHERE on database to limit data
```

In addition, I've been able to write a stored procedure to dynamically build these views by inputting the (common) table name, as well one to rebuild these whenever any new databases are added.

We are still however unsure regarding the efficiency/performance of the two solutions above, although in most cases Solution 1 seems marginally quicker, but Solution 2 has been quicker on the odd occasion. We're still to look into this further.

**My question is.. can I achieve this in a better way?**

> Advance apologies, I don't want this to be a discussion. I'd just really like some input as to whether someone already knows an easier and efficient way to achieve the above. Many thanks.

Comment: I used your solution #2, my reason is basically the debug, compile and maintenance, it is much easier to find issues and make complex queries when you have a union, about performance it may be a problem, but #2 worked well for me.